# how to zoom to a specific range for the initial plot/zoom?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, bokeh

if I have a time series range range 2015-01-01 to 2015-12-31 and I have it plotted with bokeh, but is there a way I can zoom it to the first month by default (then we can scroll out later)? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can specifically set up the range you want at the very beginning in the `figure()` call... let see it in one example:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, FB, GOOG, IBM, MSFT
from bokeh.plotting import *

output_file("stocks.html", title="stocks.py example")

left_range = np.datetime64('2000-03-01')
right_range = np.datetime64('2006-03-01')

p1 = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", x_range=[left_range, right_range])

p1.line(np.array(AAPL['date'], 'M64'), AAPL['adj_close'], color='#A6CEE3', legend='AAPL')
p1.line(np.array(FB['date'], 'M64'), FB['adj_close'], color='#1F78B4', legend='FB')
p1.line(np.array(GOOG['date'], 'M64'), GOOG['adj_close'], color='#B2DF8A', legend='GOOG')
p1.line(np.array(IBM['date'], 'M64'), IBM['adj_close'], color='#33A02C', legend='IBM')
p1.line(np.array(MSFT['date'], 'M64'), MSFT['adj_close'], color='#FB9A99', legend='MSFT')

p1.title = "Stock Closing Prices"
p1.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'

show(p1)
```

Here, I just defined left and right values for the range:

```
p1 = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", x_range=[left_range, right_range])
```

Let me know if you need more help.